# &string::at() not returning address of reference?

Tags: c++, string, reference

I'm trying to make sense of the following output of the `string.at()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name = "abc";
    std::cout << name.at(0) << '\n';
    std::cout << &name.at(0) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
a
abc
```

I am confused as why `&name.at(0)` will not return the **address** of the first char of the string, i.e. `a`. Instead, it returns the complete string.

According to the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/), `string::at` "returns a reference to the character at position pos in the string."

Comment: `&name.at(0)` does return `char*` which is the address of character `a`. Then that `char*` gets interpreted by `operator<<` as a pointer to a NUL-terminated string (which it is), and printed accordingly. If you want to print the address itself, cast to `void*`

Comment: Cast to `void*` to see the address: `(void*)&name.at(0)`

Comment: @M.M: The one in the "linked" sidebar?  Actually this is a duplicate of that one.  Both ask why inserting a `char*` to an output stream prints the string instead of the address stored in the pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt the other question involves `char *` and `char **`, whereas this involves `char` and `char *`. Maybe I was too hasty though, the underlying issue is the same as you say